# JQuery keyup not causing alert

Tags: jquery, keyup

I am testing `keyup()` by sending an alert when typing in a textfield, but nothing happens. Not sure if I need to make seperate  brackets, or if I've failed to include a library.

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>City Finder</title>
            <script 
             src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
             
              
             $(document).ready(function()
             {
                  $( "#cityField" ).keyup(function()
                  {
                      window.alert("Handler for .keyup() called.");
                  });
             });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                Enter A Utah City: <input type = "text" id="cityField" value= ""><br>
                Suggestion: <span id="txtHint">Empty</span>
                <input id="weatherButton" type ="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <p>City</p>
            <textarea id = "displayCity">No City</textarea>
            <p>Current Weather</p>
            <div id="weather">No Weather</div>
            <input type = "button" onclick = alert("hello"); name = "ok" value = "Climb out window">
           
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had some semantic issues (such as not closing the body tag), and a couple of typos - Also I moved the script block to the end of the page so that the page can load before the script is called. Make sure you close the script tags when calling an external js file into the page - they need to be in their own script tags - not joined with the in-page javascript block. Also I added the HTML5 doctype and placeholder text for the text area. You should also have labels for your inputs as well.

Also - its better for debugging to use console.log() rather than alert.

```html
<!doctype html>
 <head>
   <title>City Finder</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form>
    <label for ="cityField"> Enter A Utah City:</label>
     <input type = "text" id="cityField" value= ""><br>
      Suggestion: <span id="txtHint">Empty</span>
     <input id="weatherButton" type ="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
   <label for="displayCity">City</label><br>
   <textarea id = "displayCity" placeholder="No city"></textarea>
   <p>Current Weather</p>
   <div id="weather">No Weather</div>
     <button type = "button" onclick = "alert('hello')" name = "ok" >Climb out window</button>
            
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#cityField" ).keyup(function() {
        console.log("Handler for .keyup() called.");
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay so I ran into this issue earlier, but when i have the actual code outside of the inital <script> brackets, I get an error saying "$ is not defined". However when I have the code inside the first <script> brackets that error goes away. Any suggestions?

Comment: its probably the link to jquery library - try replacing it with the following : ... <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> - i will update the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Just close the first external script inclusion and start another script tag worked for me.

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <title>City Finder</title>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
           <script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
            
        
                  $("#cityField").keyup(function()
                  {
                      alert("This works");
                  });
             });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                Enter A Utah City: <input type = "text" id="cityField" value= ""><br>
                Suggestion: <span id="txtHint">Empty</span>
                <input id="weatherButton" type ="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            <p>City</p>
            <textarea id = "displayCity">No City</textarea>
            <p>Current Weather</p>
            <div id="weather">No Weather</div>
            <input type = "button" onclick = alert("hello"); name = "ok" value = "Climb out window">
           
    
    </html>
```